# Do Firefox "pin tab" option automatically refresh the tab every X seconds/minutes?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I just discovered this feature of Firefox 7 and I find it really interesting.
The only part I didn't understood is if it automatically refresh tabs every X time, that's really something important because I don't know if I have to do it every time I visit the page

Any information will be useful,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "pin tab" feature of FF7 doesn't refresh the page, however [ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/) will do reloads, but not for pinned tabs only, and not automatically when you defocus the tab.

So unfortunately there isn't feature within FF or any current extensions that will automatically reload a pinned tab periodically when unfocused.

Comment: You are right I'm talking about **pin tab**, which is a new feature in firefox 7 (no i don't have tab mix plus), unfortunately I traduct it wrongly from italian

Comment: Ah ok, no problem.  I have updated.

Comment: Well, not exactly what I'm thinking about: I need something that refresh only Pinned tabs and expecially when they are not selected (the timer should start when I remove focus from it and reset when it's gained)

Comment: Ok.  The answer is "no" then - there isn't feature within FF or any current extensions that will automatically reload a pinned tab periodically when unfocused.

Answer (score -1):

[Check4Change](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/check4change/) which will "periodically check a web-page for updates" does the trick.